# ffmpeg - remuxing a TS file with multiple audio streams

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Hi newbie ffmpeg user here with ffmpeg v3.2.4 on a Win7 Ultimate x64 PC.

I have a number of .TS files which I'm trying to remux to .MP4. In addition to the video stream and the usual audio stream, some have two audio streams, where the first is a Narrative (NAR) stream and the second is the actual audio content I want. When remuxing using the command line
                         ffmpeg -i input.ts -c copy output.mp4
ffmpeg uses the NAR stream instead of the second audio stream. How do I get it to use the second audio stream instead please?

Many thanks

Alan

Comment: Sorry the command line got garbled. It should be:  ffmpeg -i input.ts -c copy output.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy **all** streams

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0 -c copy output.mp4
```

To copy **all audio** streams

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy output.mp4
```

To copy **only 2nd audio** stream

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:v -map 0:a:1 -c copy output.mp4
```